# Can't set proper path to file

Tags: java

I've tried several methods of achieving the proper pathing to the file using Path but I've had no success so far. I am trying to write/rewrite the file.

In the code snippets I'll show what I've tried so far but I can't seem to get the right path down. Also here's an example hierarchy of my packages

```
src
├── information
│   └── destination
│       └── (empty)
└── classpackage
    └── MyClass.java
```

I'm trying to keep the path relative to the project itself so anyone can compile it and have the file be created in the correct place within the hierarchy of packages of the project, no matter where they put the src folder.

This is inside MyClass.java

```
private static final File FILE = new File("/src/information/destination", "data.set");

ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(FILE.getAbsolutePath())); //doesn't work

ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(FILE)); //doesn't work

ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(FILE.getAbsoluteFile())); //doesn't work
```

Comment: Does `data.set` inside the `src\information\destination` folder exist? If not, then it appears that you're trying to read input from a nonexistent file.

Comment: Is `src` in the root?

Comment: What you seem to want is called a _resource_ and should not be accessed in the same way a file is—see [`Class#getResource(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)). Note that resources should be considered read-only.

Comment: Every line of this code is wrong in multiple ways. You are just guessing. Your file does not exist, the file path is wrong, and using Objectinputsream is absurd.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the absolute path and use that to refer the file you want. Java provides FileSystem for help. Add the file path of your file after getting the absolute path.

```
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;

class FileRead {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String filePath =
        FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(".").
        toAbsolutePath()+"/Practice/Stack";
        File file = new File(filePath,"test.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String st; 
        while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(st); 
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }finally{}
  }
}
```

Comment: There are some improvements one could make to this code. Regarding the use of NIO, see [`Paths.get(String,String...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get(java.lang.String,java.lang.String...)), [`Path.resolve(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve(java.lang.String)), and [`Files.newBufferedReader(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader(java.nio.file.Path)).

Comment: It's also better to use `e.printStackTrace()` rather than simply printing the message as it provides more information. The `finally` is not necessary here. And although this is a short-lived application, it's good practice to close a resource when finished with it—see [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Also, if one must interoperate between `File` and `Path`, use [`Path.toFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#toFile()).

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can change the path to. src/information/destination

and the file path like

[image]
Solution:

```
package classpackge;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

public class MyClass {
    private static final File FILE = new File("src/information/destination", "data.set");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        FileInputStream in =new FileInputStream(FILE.getAbsolutePath()); //doesn't work
in.close();
        //ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(FILE)); //doesn't work

        //ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(FILE.getAbsoluteFile())); //doesn't work
    }
}
```